# multivaraible chain rule proof

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I wanted to prove the multivaraible chain rule; I had to prove that $df \large \frac {({x(t)},{y(t)})}{dt}  = \frac{∂ f}{∂ x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{∂ f}{∂ y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$

So, I took the differential:  $df    = \frac{∂ f}{∂ x}\cdot dx + \frac{∂ f}{∂ y}\cdot dy + \frac{∂ f}{∂ t}\cdot dt$

I then doubled it all by $ \large \frac{1}{dt}$

and got $\large \frac{df}{dt}    = \frac{∂ f}{∂ x}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{∂ f}{∂ y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{∂ f}{∂ t}\cdot \frac{dt}{dt}$

which yields:  $\large \frac{df}{dt}    = \frac{∂ f}{∂ x}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{∂ f}{∂ y}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{∂ f}{∂ t}$

at which point I'm stuck and can go no further..

Comment: But the function itself is not **directly** dependent to t?

Comment: I think it's  $F = F(x,y,t)$

Comment: Take this for example You have  $x(t)=t^2$ , and $y(t)=4t$ 
And then you define $f(x(t),y(t))=x^2+y^2$ etc.

Comment: you are right...time to rethink this then..

Comment: it depends on how $f$ depends on $t$. Only indirectly like $f(x(t),y(t))$ or directly  $f(x(t),y(t),t)$. In the former case $\partial_t f$ is trivially zero and the result you shoulb prove is correct.

Comment: it becomes a very trivial proof then...is it possible?

Comment: Your task is to prove the simplest case of the multivariable chain rule. This cannot be done juggling letters around. Instead it involves certain limit considerations.